# SwipeToDismiss & nestedScroll does not work well together - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, swipe-gesture

I am trying to implement a list of items with the ability to delete items with swipe. I've basically used `LazyColumn` and `SwipeToDismiss` composables.

With default configuration vertical scrolling of LazyColumn and horizontal swiping of `SwipeToDismiss` mixes and I mostly trigger SwipeToDismiss while trying to do verticall scrolling.

To be able to change sensitivity of `SwipeToDismiss` I've looked how touch system works. As far as I understand children composables should ask to parents before consuming dragging events and parents can consume before children by utilizing [nestedScroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)). But there is a problem with `SwipeToDismiss`, it does not dispatch drag events to parents if the dragging angle on the x&y axis is between 0 & 45 degrees. So parents are not able to consume dragging events.

The problem is reproducable by changing the example on the [nestedScroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)) documentation page. Just replace the items with `SwipeToDismiss`. You can also find the changed example source code below.

I am trying to understand if this is this a bug, or am I missing something and how can I make `SwipeToDismiss` and vertical scrolling work together better.

```
// here we use LazyColumn that has build-in nested scroll, but we want to act like a
// parent for this LazyColumn and participate in its nested scroll.
// Let's make a collapsing toolbar for LazyColumn
    val toolbarHeight = 48.dp
    val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { toolbarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
// our offset to collapse toolbar
    val toolbarOffsetHeightPx =

        remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
// now, let's create connection to the nested scroll system and listen to the scroll
// happening inside child LazyColumn
    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                // try to consume before LazyColumn to collapse toolbar if needed, hence pre-scroll
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
                toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-toolbarHeightPx, 0f)
                // here's the catch: let's pretend we consumed 0 in any case, since we want
                // LazyColumn to scroll anyway for good UX
                // We're basically watching scroll without taking it
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            // attach as a parent to the nested scroll system
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        // our list with build in nested scroll support that will notify us about its scroll
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = toolbarHeight)) {
            items(100) { index ->
                val state = remember { DismissState(DismissValue.Default) { true } }
                SwipeToDismiss(state = state, background = {
                    Text(text = "Background", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Red))
                }) {
                    Text("I'm item $index", modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(color = Color.Black)
                        .padding(16.dp))
                }

            }
        }
        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(toolbarHeight)
                .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) },
            title = { Text("toolbar offset is ${toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value}") }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Default SwipeToDismiss behavior is really easy to implement but hard to use.

Comment: Having same problem. Please post if you find any solution